# how to set date and time for diffrent country

Tags: php, datetime

I want to set date and time like Facebook. If any american post any comment then he shows american time but I show this comment from India so I show Indian time.

Now I am using this code for the set Indian time:

```
$timezone = "Asia/Kolkata";
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$time=date("h:i a");
$date = date("M d,Y");
```

Problem in this code is all country's user show only Indian time.
So what can i do for this?

Comment: You should take into account the timezone of your user, not the timezone of your server as it is now. Note that this can become very tricky, you'll find a lot of people struggling with the same kind of issues during your researches on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to determine user's location, for example with [GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing). Second, you'll need to know somehow which timezone is used in this location, for example with some sort of online API, for example - [by Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/).